# Is it okay to eat right after exercising in terms of the sweat that might be pouring from my body?

Tags: diet, health, hygiene

Usually, after exercise, I cool down and then do other stuff for about 15-20 minutes and then take a bath.

Is it okay to instead eat a full meal after those 15-20 minutes before taking a bath if I just wash my hands?

I was thinking that it might be unsanitary since my body would have been sweating a lot.

Comment: What are you eating? This question is a little broad... If it is healthy and not too much, I'd say it's fine.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It's not just OK but is also recommended. When you end your exercises your body needs food, especially proteins and good carbs !! But i won't enter in nutritional aspects of this because your question appear to be about hygiene.

It's ok to eat if you just wash your hands, there's no harm on that because normally the rest of your body won't touch your food right? And sweat anyway isn't bad for your health you can even drink it! The only possible harm is the bacteria on your hands, but washing your hands for 1min is enough.

Comment: Second that, there is nothing specially dangerous to your health about body sweat. The bacteria there is the same you have on your skin and unless your workout involves digging in a landfill you should be already exposed to then anyway. Wash your hands and you will be fine.

Comment: WTH http://news.discovery.com/tech/save-water-drink-your-own-sweat-130717.htm Lol. Thanks Freedom.

Answer (score 1):

**Is it okay to instead eat a full meal after those 15-20 minutes before taking a bath if I just wash my hands?**

**Yes**, there is **no set time** for you to consume your post workout meal.

Comment: My concern is the leftover sweat. Am I or am I not too unhygenic to eat?

Comment: It's nothing to do with stuff like wait 1 hr after eating before swimming due to possible digestion problems or whatever

Comment: This should be **personal preference**. If you asked me, I will probably take a bath before eating.

Comment: @BCLC 1 hour after eating before swimming is an old wive's tale.

Comment: @JohnP [vigorous exercise directs blood flow away from the digestive area to the skin and to the muscles in your arms, legs and skin. So, if your food is still half-digested this could make you nauseous. It’s the same reason that extreme fear makes you feel sick. The fight-or-flight response abandons less-urgent processes like digestion, diverting blood flow to the muscles so that you can defend yourself physically, or run faster than you ever have before.](http://www.bbc.com/future/story/20130401-can-you-swim-just-after-eating)

Comment: Yes, I know. You might feel a little sick, but it's very much by individual. There is still no evidence that it produces cramps or incapacitates you.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you should eat after working out, especially protein. Protein is what helps muscles recover after a workout, and eating after working out helps nutrients flow to your muscles quicker.

Comment: My concern is the leftover sweat

Comment: @BCLC Wipe down your hands, arms, face, etc. and then eat if you are worried about it. This will take only 1-2 minutes. Either way, I haven't heard of health concerns about sweat other than the high sodium level, and I have met some athletes that actually even drink their sweat.

Answer (score -3):

It is actually recommended that you have your post workout meal in the 15-20 minute window post workout. Since your question is about hygiene I would say it does not matter as long as your food doesnt touch the sweat. 
 Keep in mind that showering immediately after a meal will affect your digestion, as it will divert the blood flow from the stomach to other parts of the body, affecting the digestive process. Wait for sometime before heading for the shower.

Comment: "It is actually recommended that you have your post workout meal in the 15-20 minute window post workout." This is largely broscience, put in place by the manufacturers of protein shakes. Because protein shakes are the most convenient post-workout meal.

Comment: @Abhishek, those are some pretty bold claims, I'd need to see supporting evidence to back them up.

Comment: This is a misinterpretation of the timing recommended to consume carbohydrates with some protein to restore muscle glycogen. As can be seen in [studies like this](http://jap.physiology.org/content/93/4/1337.short), a 3:1 carb to protein ratio is ideal for replenishing muscle glycogen. Supplement companies jumped on this and push the misinformation as @Alec stated. This more applies to endurance exercise than it does to weightlifting types of exercise.